# Is there a variant of sscanf with pointer to input string instead of buffers?

Tags: c, parsing, scanf, tokenize

`sscanf` works like this:

```
int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char buf1[1024] = {0};
    char buf2[1024] = {0};
    char buf3[1024] = {0};
    char *str = "abc, 123; xyz";
    sscanf(str, "%[^,], %[^;]; %s", buf1, buf2, buf3);
    printf("'%s' '%s' '%s'", buf1, buf2, buf3); // Prints: "'abc' '123' 'xyz'"
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a function which does not require copying the contents of `str` into the buffers (`buf1, buf2, buf3`), nor allocating any new memory. Instead it would just set the pointers (`ptr1, ptr2, ptr3`) to point at the matching parts in `str` and null terminate whatever comes after the match.

```
int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *ptr1 = NULL;
    char *ptr2 = NULL;
    char *ptr3 = NULL;
    char *str = "abc, 123; xyz";
    //
    // str = "abc, 123; xyz\0"
    //
    _sscanf(str, "%[^,], %[^;]; %s", &ptr1, &ptr2, &ptr3);
    //
    // str = "abc\0 123\0 xyz\0"
    //        ^     ^     ^
    //       ptr1  ptr2  ptr3
    //
    printf("'%s' '%s' '%s'", ptr1, ptr2, ptr3); // Prints: "'abc' '123' 'xyz'"

    return 0;
}
```

I know there are functions such as `strtok_r` and the `regex.h` library which could be used, but I think this would be more convenient in cases where the input string can be modified.

Comment: The problem is that the input parsed by `sscanf` cannot *always* be null-terminated! The `regex.h` returns *ranges* of the subgroup matches - that would be doable.

Comment: Your question is an nonsense as if you null terminate the original string somewhere in the middle, you will never be the same string str anymore, as you will overwrite something BTW even if you move the rest of if right the size of the str will increase and most likely reallocation will be required

Comment: Note that I said in some cases. In some cases I do not care whether the input string is modified.

Comment: The arguments to `main()` aren't `const`.

Comment: I just declare them `const` by default as I prefer them to be immutable

Comment: The idea would not work for string literals (your `str` points to that literal!), because they are actually const. Their contents cannot be modified. -- The idea, while interesting, is also anti-paradigmatic to the `*scanf`  semantics, which are: Take some input and create a *separate* textual representation of it. It is true that that functionality is redundant in the case of an input which is already text, namely a C string. But that is just a special part of a more general concept of what `scanf`  does.

Comment: As per the C Standard Appendix J2 in a hosted environment `main` shall either be defined as `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char**)` else the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @alk I assume that the signature of an `f(const T)` is indistinguishable from an `f(T)`: the argument declaration is merely an assert for the implementation, not part of the signature. For example, in C++ it is not possible to overload a function with one that just has const arguments. Considering that, would you think about `main(const int, char **const)`? Which is potentially what the OP meant anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't pretty but the `%n` specifier might be used to capture the index to the start and end of the tokens. Error checking would make sure the index and end values are not `-1`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int index1 = -1;
    int end1 = -1;
    int index2 = -1;
    int end2 = -1;
    int index3 = -1;
    int end3 = -1;
    char *str = "abc, 123; xyz";
    sscanf(str, " %n%*[^,]%n, %n%*[^;]%n; %n%*s%n", &index1, &end1, &index2, &end2, &index3, &end3);
    printf("'%.*s' '%.*s' '%.*s'", end1, str + index1, end2 - index2, str + index2, end3 - index3, str + index3); // Prints: "'abc' '123' 'xyz'"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `index1` is redundant, but I guess you left it there for consistency with other indices.

Comment: Oh, I must've missed the space when I first read the format string. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standardized variant which ends up with pointers to `char *` pointing to locations in your original string. There's a variant in POSIX that allocates memory for, and copies the data to, each string item.

The functionality of `sscanf()` matches the functionality of `fscanf()` and the other variants, and within very broad limits, what applies to one variant applies to all.  What you're seeking, though, couldn't be applied to the file-based variants, so it doesn't exist.

---

There is a variant of [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) that allocates memory for strings.  It's the POSIX 2008 variant of `sscanf()`, and the `m` modifier.

> [CX] ⌦ The `%c`, `%s`, and `%[` conversion specifiers shall accept an optional assignment-allocation character 'm', which shall cause a memory buffer to be allocated to hold the string converted including a terminating null character. In such a case, the argument corresponding to the conversion specifier should be a reference to a pointer variable that will receive a pointer to the allocated buffer. The system shall allocate a buffer as if `malloc()` had been called. The application shall be responsible for freeing the memory after usage. If there is insufficient memory to allocate a buffer, the function shall set `errno` to `[ENOMEM]` and a conversion error shall result. If the function returns EOF, any memory successfully allocated for parameters using assignment-allocation character 'm' by this call shall be freed before the function returns. ⌫

The [CX] notation marks this as an extension over the C standard (so the `m` modifier is not a part of Standard C and it is not supported everywhere), and the ⌦ and ⌫ symbols mark the scope of the extension.

Thus, if your implementation supports it (Linux does, for example; macOS Sierra does not), there is a variation of `sscanf()` that will allocate buffers of the correct size for you, and it takes `char **` arguments.

The man page on Linux says:

> An optional 'm' character.  This is used with string conversions (`%s`, `%c`, `%[`), and relieves  the  caller  of  the  need to allocate a corresponding buffer to hold the input: instead, `scanf()` allocates a buffer of sufficient  size, and assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding pointer argument, which should be a pointer to a `char *` variable (this variable does not need to be initialized  before the call). The caller should subsequently free(3) this buffer when it is no longer required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "The hills are alive with the sound of music";
    char *w[9];

    if (sscanf(data, "%ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms",
               &w[0], &w[1], &w[2], &w[3], &w[4], &w[5], &w[6], &w[7], &w[8]) != 9)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Forwards: %s\n", data);
    printf("Reversed:");
    for (int i = 8; i >= 0; i--)
        printf(" %s", w[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        free(w[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Forwards: The hills are alive with the sound of music
Reversed: music of sound the with alive are hills The
```

Comment: This still copies the strings, though.  It does not return pointers into the input string, which is what OP asked for,

Comment: @zwol: Oh, I misread the question first time around.  I've revised my answer correspondingly.

Comment: The `m` modifier also works with Posix `scanf` and `fscanf`. (I know you know that, but your answer could be misinterpreted, I think.)